# Determinant of an eigenmatrix of a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix with eigenvalue decomposition $A = VDV^\top$. In this case, the eigenmatrix $V$ is orthogonal and thus the determinant of $V$ is either $1$ or $-1$. Is there a case where the determinant of $V$ is always $1$, a pure rotational matrix?
Thanks

Comment: Note: assuming that $A$ is symmetric *means* that $A^\top = A$, so you don't need to assume it separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the sign of $\det V$ by negating one of the eigenvectors, i.e. columns of $V$:
$$
\mathbf{v}_i \mapsto -\mathbf{v}_i
$$
or by swapping the two columns
$$
\mathbf{v}_i \leftrightarrow \mathbf{v}_j
$$
Let $U$ denote the resulting matrix after doing one of these operations on $V$.

**Claim:** $U$ is *special* orthogonal, i.e. $U^\top U = I$ and $\det U = 1$.

As a result the matrix $D' = U^{-1} A U$ is also diagonal. Hence,
$$
A = U D' U^{-1} = U D' U^\top
$$
is still a factorization in terms of eigenbasis and eigenvalues.

In the first case, the $D' = D$, and in the latter case, $D'$ has the two diagonal entries at index $i$ and $j$ swapped.